# How can I remove comment - Quote redwaves-lite

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I use a free wordpress template (redwaves-lite) , it is a very nice theme but  has a small bug , if there is a large number of comment with quote , It looks bad , here is the picture :

https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-sLBXWHBoZ0Q/WUB0lMGiYTI/AAAAAAAA8bk/7wK-cIbHUWkPujgr9MePIhg31jjGJV-egCLcBGAs/s1600/11462.jpg

How can I remove comment - Quote
Theme download link:
https://wordpress.org/themes/redwaves-lite/

Comment: Is this the comments on the blog post section?

Comment: Yes, in the quote
<Li
How can i remove